# Django admin, how can I add the FK selector in a StackedInline record

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

Given the following models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    family = models.ForeignKey(
        "Family", related_name="members", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

And the following admin settings:

```py
class PersonAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person
    list_display = ("name", "family")

    extra = 0

class FamilyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Family
    list_display = ("name",)

    inlines = [PersonAdmin]

    extra = 0

admin.site.register(Family, FamilyAdmin)
```

How, from the Family edit page, can I change the family of a person?

Say I have ***Person A*** belonging to ***Family 1***. I would like to be able to migrate this person to another family from the family edit page.

Unfortunately, even if I explicitly specify the fields in the PersonAdmin class, the dropdown won't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom `form` to the `PersonAdmin` class and override the `__init__()` method to dynamically add a `ModelChoiceField` for selecting the new family of a person.

Try this:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Family, Person


class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    new_family = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Family.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        label="New Family",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["name", "family", "new_family"]


class PersonAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person
    list_display = ("name", "family")
    extra = 0
    form = PersonForm  # Here we Added custom form


class FamilyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Family
    list_display = ("name",)
    inlines = [PersonAdmin]
    extra = 0


admin.site.register(Family, FamilyAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight, that was exactly what I was looking for !

I managed to reach my goal by updating the PersonForm to populate with a default value and updating the original family field to change family. (by overriding the init and save methods).